# Function Rules & Messages for a form Create and Edit

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a function `rules` and `messages` to manage error messages. When the user enters severals values on my form create, the verification system works well.

Here is an example with the field `name`.

I enter a value numeric there is an error message

[image]

Then, I enter a value alphabetical

[image]

It's ok

Now, my problem is that When I want to edit my value Alain with a value numeric I don't have an error message like on the form create. I don't understand why?

[image]

I just want to display the error message.

Here is my code:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:25|min:3|alpha'
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [

            'name.required' => "REQUIRED",
            'name' => "MESSAGE",
            'name.alpha' => "The characters must be alphabetical.",

        ];
    }
```

What is the manipulation for the form edit please?

Comment: Is it possible that the `string` validator is the one that's failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize your method is currently using the Laravel validation, and this will require some type of input back to the server to go through that validation, and then return to the form.  This is great, and important to have on the server side for sure.

However, there are occasionally elements that might supersede your return message.  An example might be that the validator is tripping on the `string` or `min` rules *before* it gets to the alpha rule.  And just like in an `if check`, the first one to trip is the one that is going to send the message.  In this case, because you don't have those defined, it *might* be sending nothing rather than the alpha rule message.

For this and several other reasons, developers sometimes use multiple stages of validation.  The bottom layer, or the strongest, would be like you have it, on the server.  This stops bad stuff from getting into your database.

But, it is sometimes a little slow and a little clunky from the user experience perspective.  So it might help to **also** add client side validation to your forms.  A good one is [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/).  This type of client side validation gives *instant* response to the user (because it doesn't have to go back to the server), and it prevents wasted trips to the server with bad form data (it checks before submitting to the server if there are rules broken).  Thus, you would not actually hit the Laravel validator until the jQuery validator has done its work -- and you would likely end up with very few issues on the Laravel validator side.

If you don't use this already, it might be worth your time to take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations and the time you spent writing to me. I'm going to learn Ajax.